# C++ code using while(cin>>) fails to terminate and output the answer to the last query

Tags: c++, while-loop, cin, getline

My implementation of While(cin>>) fails to terminate and output the last query

I tried searching similar implementations and they all ran correctly. Even those exactly the same as my while loop, however mine fails to do so (output the last query and exit program)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int dp[1001][1001];
string temp1, temp2;

void clear(){
    for(int i=0; i<1001; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<1001; j++){
            dp[i][j] = -1; 
        }
    }
}

int lcs(int i, int j){
    if(i==0 || j==0){
        dp[i][j] = 0;
        return dp[i][j];
    }
    else if(dp[i][j]>0){
        return dp[i][j];
    }
    else{
        if(temp1[i-1] == temp2[j-1]){
            dp[i][j] = lcs(i-1, j-1) + 1;  
        }
        else{
            if(lcs(i-1, j) > lcs(i, j-1)){
                dp[i][j] = lcs(i-1, j);
            }
            else{
                dp[i][j] = lcs(i, j-1);
            }
        }


        return dp[i][j]; 
    }
}

int main(){


    while(getline(cin,temp1)){ 
        getline(cin, temp2); 
        clear();
        cout<<lcs(temp1.length(), temp2.length())<<endl;
    }

    return 0; 
}
```

Program does not terminate

Comment: Depending on your operating system you can end waiting for input from `std::cin` pressing CTRL-D or CTRL-Z.

Comment: Yep! However, this still does not solve my problem of the program not giving the output to the final input.

Comment: What do you mean by "final input"?

Comment: @melpomene For example, I input 5 sets (10 lines total) of input for temp1 and temp2. The program does not output the answer, (largest common sub sequence) for the last set.

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. Also, https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/.